# How to get tokens different resources msal2

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

With msal v2, i dont see how  i can get tokens for different Resources.
This is a simple SPA that calls 2 different APIS(2 different Resources on b2c).
How is this supported?
Why do i need to log in for every different Service?
With log in method, you have to specify the scope and i can not set more than one scope from different resources.
following this example but with 2 resources, wont work.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-spa-dotnetcore-webapi-obo

if we follow this kind of Arquitecture arent we falling on a funnel problem where all the calls will be redirected to a single point?

Answer (score 1):

The understanding is correct. Currently AAD B2C /authorize endpoint only allows consenting to a single resource. And the Refresh token is bound to only be traded to get access tokens for those scopes consented to at the /authorize call.

Understandably, as you say, it means essentially your backend APIs are modelled as one single resource. You can consent to 30 scopes on one resource.

Work is ongoing to change this behaviour such that the refresh token can be traded for multiple different resources.

If you are using a SPA application, the acquisition of new tokens is reliant on session cookies, and this approach does not have the above limitations. Only PKCE SPA apps relying on Refresh tokens have this issue. .Net apps also have this limitation.

Comment: Thank you @jas-suri-msft   i actually had it like that with the Implicit flow and the MSAL v1, BUt reading on MIcrosoft docs, they encourage to update to PKCE und use the new Version of the library.

Comment: Yes we prefer PKCE, soon we will improve this to get tokens to any resource that has been consented go in the azure portal.

Comment: can i kow the estimated that for this feature? also i though to resolve this making one single entry point API,and from this call the other APIs, unfourtunatley this call DownstreamApis call doenst work on B2C as well. anycurrent solution for this microservices architecture?

Comment: The only thing that could work is a API gateway that represents a single resource and then that uses AAD Client Credentials to get a new token to do further API calls into the backends. ETA is at least 3 months for multi resource refresh tokens.